# PHP - how can I get the number of characters in an array value?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to get a character count from a group of values in an array, so I can test it in an if statement.

Best if I give you an example of what I want to do:

```
//sample

$content = '<p>this is p 1</p><p>this is p 2</p><p>this is p 3</p><p>this is p 4</p><p>$test</p>';
$parts = explode('</p>',$content);

foreach ($parts as $key => $value) {
  $test = count_chars($value[0] + $value[1] + $value[2]);

  if ($test > 40) {
    echo 'Yep, there are '.$test.' characters in the first three paragraphs<br />';
  }
  else { 
    echo 'Nope. There are '.$test.' characters in the first three paragraphs<br />'; 
  }
}
```

I don't work with arrays much, so not sure how to do this. Right now `$test` just gives me 'array'.

And I know this is going to repeat the same string, this is not the final product, stripped out as many details as I could so we could focus on the situation I'm stuck on :)

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What else did you try to achieve your goal? Of cours `count_chars` returns an array, as given in the documentation. Have you tried dumping it to inspect the content, such that you see what it returns?

Comment: Using `explode('</p>',$content)` may not give you exactly what you are after, you result will still have the open tags `<p>`.

Comment: I suggest to work with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this solution:**

if you want to check only first 3 paragraphs then you don't need any for each loop.

```
<?php

$content = '<p>this is p 1</p><p>this is p 2</p><p>this is p 3</p><p>this is p 4</p><p>$test</p>';

$parts = explode('</p>', $content);

$test = strlen($parts[0].$parts[1].$parts[2]);

    if ($test > 40) {
        echo 'Yep, there are ' . $test . ' characters in the first three paragraphs<br />';
    } 
    else {
        echo 'Nope. There are ' . $test . ' characters in the first three paragraphs<br />';
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: sure @NicoHaase

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments and suggested answers here! This answer with the use of strlen and how to format the parameters is exactly what I needed. Thank you Muhammad.

Comment: @MuhammadShahid this would even be a better answer if you added some explanation to it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count all character use `strlen()` insted of `count_chars()` like this

```
$test = strlen($value[0].$value[1].$value[2]);
```

`count_chars()` function will returns information about characters used in a string (for example, how many times an ASCII character occurs in a string, or which characters that have been used or not been used in a string) [count_chars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

and you don't need use `foreach()` since `explode()` will give you one dimension array, simply what you need is just like this

```
$value = explode('</p>',$content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't mind the extra `<p>` parts of the string being counted, you could simplify this to using `implode()` without a seperator as it will just put all of the parts back together and then take the `strlen()` of the result...

```
$parts = explode('</p>',$content);

$test = strlen(implode($parts));
```

Using `count_chars()` isn't correct as it *Counts the number of occurrences of every byte-value (0..255) in string and returns it in various ways.*.

Also using `+` is adding numeric values and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-reduce.php). This handles a variable number of values in your `$content`.

`array_reduce` takes each value of the array and performs the callback on it. The returned value is then somehow mixed together with the results of the previous content.

In the following code `array_reduce` takes the initial value `0` as `$carray`. Then it takes the first element from the `$content` array (as `$text`) and adds the length of the `$text` to the `$carray`. The result is the new `$carray` for the next array value. This generates the full length.

```php
$content = '<p>this is p 1</p><p>this is p 2</p><p>this is p 3</p><p>this is p 4</p><p>$test</p>';

$parts = explode('</p>', $content);

$test = array_reduce($parts, function($carry, $text){
    return strlen($text) + $carry; 
}, 0);
```

---

Note that your `$content` still has the `<p>` tags which are counted. There are a few ways to count only the text without the tags. The easiest but also least flexible way is to use [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strip-tags). This will count your text but all tags are removed.

```php
$content = '<p>this is p 1</p><p>this is p 2</p><p>this is p 3</p><p>this is p 4</p><p>$test</p>';

$test = strlen(strip_tags($content));
```

Another possibility is to remove the `<p>` tags by e.g. replacing them. I would prefere a regular expression but in exact this case `str_replace` is enough:

```php
$content = '<p>this is p 1</p><p>this is p 2</p><p>this is p 3</p><p>this is p 4</p><p>$test</p>';

$parts = explode('</p>', $content);

$test = array_reduce($parts, function($carry, $text){
    return strlen(str_replace("<p>", "", $text)) + $carry; 
}, 0);
```

Depending on what you need you can also parse your html. This is a lot more powerful but may also be too much:

```php
$content = '<p>this is p 1</p><p>this is p 2</p><p>this is p 3</p><p>this is p 4</p><p>$test</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<html><body>".$content."</body></html>");

$test = strlen($dom->textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

[count_chars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) have `$mode` as 0 by default. See:

[image]

You can call it with different mode to get a string as a result. But based on what you described, this is not what you want. You will need to call [strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) instead:

```
$totalLength = $myStringArray[0];
for ($index = 1; $index < count($myStringArray); $index++) {
    $totalLength += $myStringArray[$index];
}
```

as about the explode, you are removing the `</p>` from the string, which I suppose is your actual goal. But you still left `<p>` inside the string. You will need to remove it too if you want to exclude it. You can use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for that purpose, like:

```
$length = str_replace('<p>', '', str_replace('</p>', '', $content));
```

Comment: The screenshot of the PHP manual is not terribly helpful and it discriminates against users with vision impairments.

Comment: @mickmackusa I surely did not mean to discriminate anyone. Maybe opening the screenshot in a new tab is helpful. There is also a link to the page one can open if that's more helpful.